# Cosine similarity with BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, vector, google-bigquery

I have vectors stored in BigQuery (see [How can I compute TF/IDF with SQL (BigQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028576/how-can-i-compute-tf-idf-with-sql-bigquery)), and I want to find the most similar between them. How can I compute the cosine similarity with BigQuery standard SQL?

Answer (score 6):

This query looks at the vector defined for each doc, given its dimensions (by word) and multiplies them with the cosine distance formula:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(title2) orig, ANY_VALUE(tf2id) id_orig, a.id id_similar 
  , ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE( SUM(b.tf_idf * IFNULL(c.tf_idf,0)),(SQRT(SUM(b.tf_idf*b.tf_idf))*SQRT(SUM(POW(IFNULL(c.tf_idf,0),2))))),4) distance
  , ANY_VALUE(title1) similar
  , ARRAY_AGG((ROUND(b.tf_idf,4), ROUND(c.tf_idf,4))) weights
  , ARRAY_AGG((b.word, c.word)) words
FROM (
  SELECT id, tfidfs tf1, tf2, tf2id
  , a.title title1
  , b.title title2
  FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow.tf_idf_experiment_3` a
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT tfidfs tf2, id tf2id, title 
    FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow.tf_idf_experiment_3`
    WHERE id = 11353679 
    LIMIT 1
  ) b
) a
, UNNEST(tf1) b LEFT JOIN UNNEST(tf2) c ON b.word=c.word
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

First result is the same document, proving that we get distance 1 on itself:

[image]

Second result:

[image]

Etc:

[image]

Caveat: This SQL code does a LEFT JOIN, so we only get nulls for words on the left document not on the right, and not the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Great answer from [@Felipe Hoffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132438/felipe-hoffa). Cosine distance (as well as Euclidean and Manhattan distances) are now native functions in BigQuery.

For two vectors (stored as arrays) `a` and `b`, `1 - ML.DISTANCE(a, b, 'COSINE')` yields the cosine similarity for a, b.

Docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-distance

Relationship between Cosine distance and Cosine similarity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Cosine_Distance