# TF/IDF Measurement with using MySQL

Tags: mysql, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

i have following datas in my mysql weightallofwordsintopic table.

`Topic Name         Word   WordCount
20160401-20160405   ahlak   954
20160401-20160405   çocuk   825
20160401-20160405   kadın   764
20160401-20160405   tecavüz 710
20160401-20160405   güzel   701
20160401-20160405   hayat   670
20160401-20160405   bakan   661
20160401-20160405   zaman   585
20160401-20160405   adam    494
20160401-20160405   çalış   453
20160406-20160407   kandil  4927
20160406-20160407   mübarek 2906
20160406-20160407   hayır   2342
20160406-20160407   çocuk   1893
20160406-20160407   güzel   1835
20160406-20160407   regaip  1574
20160406-20160407   allah   1536
20160406-20160407   tecavüz 1457
20160406-20160407   kadın   1442
20160406-20160407   hayat   1436
20160408-20160409   güzel   2385
20160408-20160409   hayat   2187
20160408-20160409   hayır   1972
20160408-20160409   zaman   1902
20160408-20160409   cuma    1589
20160408-20160409   allah   1550
20160408-20160409   gece    1233
20160408-20160409   adam    1198
20160408-20160409   saat    1153
20160408-20160409   dünya   1130
20160410-20160411   stat    1993
20160410-20160411   güzel   1854
20160410-20160411   hayat   1579
20160410-20160411   şampiyon 1464
20160410-20160411   taraftar 1426
20160410-20160411   zaman   1380
20160410-20160411   adam    1336
20160410-20160411   çalış   1297
20160410-20160411   saat    1283
20160410-20160411   başkan  1112`

i would like to measure the tf/idf frequency for each word in each topic. Suppose a topic with same name as one document so i need to measure tf/idf frequency for all words seperately. I need mysql query for this.WordCount is the occurency of that words in that topic. My table is too large i just wrote a sample to explain my problem. I need a query to do this work. Thank you very much.

Comment: here is a sample sql in BigQuery (google cloud), probably you can implement similar in mySql: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028576/how-can-i-compute-tf-idf-with-sql-bigquery

Comment: @anonyXmous, i saw that sample but i could not convert it according to my demands with less knowledge in mysql

Comment: It is better to run tf idf in R or Python. Both have libraries that will give tou the result rather than implementing a new one in mysql. Is it your requirement to use ONLY mysql?

Comment: @anonyXmous unfortunately yes, all of my work depends to these datas and i have to find a solution by using mysql. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Okey, i'm up to this challenge. Working on it. Use only mysql to calculate tf-idf.  You have the wordcount already so this is a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it based on this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf): . 
Here you go:
1) t1 gets the sum of words per topic
2) t2 gets the idf. This is the log10 of number of topics over the number of topics that contains this word 
3) Since you did the wordcount, divide this by sum_per_topic to get tf

```
select w.Topic_Name, 
       w.Word, 
       w.WordCount/t1.topic_sum as tf, 
       t2.idf, 
       (w.WordCount/t1.topic_sum)*(t2.idf) as tf_idf
from weightallofwordsintopic w
join (
      select Topic_Name, sum(WordCount) as topic_sum  
      from weightallofwordsintopic
      group by Topic_Name
      ) t1
on w.Topic_Name=t1.Topic_Name
join (
      select w.Word, log10(t_cnts.cnts/count(*)) as idf 
      from weightallofwordsintopic w,
        (select count(distinct Topic_Name) as cnts from weightallofwordsintopic) t_cnts
      group by w.Word
      ) t2
on w.Word=t2.Word
order by tf_idf desc, 
         w.Word
```